# Strange Apache Error Log Entry

Tags: apache-http-server

Quick noob question, I have been trouble shooting a modsec problem for the past 2 days and constantly reload the apache error log.

I just suddenly found these entries in the error log and I have no idea what they mean:

```
[Sun Oct 03 10:40:09.615611 2021] [php7:error] [pid 1872] [client 123.58.212.83:39916] script '/var/www/html/douyinpay.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 03 10:40:11.059455 2021] [php7:error] [pid 2556] [client 123.58.212.83:41812] script '/var/www/html/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 03 10:40:11.078750 2021] [php7:error] [pid 2556] [client 123.58.212.83:41812] script '/var/www/html/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

I did a quick search.  I do not have anything related to douyinpay on my server (in fact, freshly build server, with 1 wordpress install)

How should I intepret / react to these entries?
It appears someone was searching for files that don't exist on my server.

Comment: Yep a script is scanning the server. Google "Fail2ban". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban

Comment: *"How should I intepret / react to these entries?"* -- You can choose to effectively blacklist or otherwise block access those files/paths in Apache, but as those scripts don't exist, there likely isn't much danger (assuming your server is configured securely, of course). Random scripts scan web servers all the time and you'll almost see more of these types of entries.